# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error from local domain to public API

Tags: angularjs, cross-domain, cors, restangular

I'm trying to create an app that will retrieve the stock name, asking and buy price from Yahoo Finance API, using Restangular. I'm having a problem with accessing a public API in the local application I'm creating when I do a GET request. This is the URL with parameters that I'm sending:

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=MSFT+GE&f=nab

Using Postman, this get request returns an array which contains the stock name, asking price and buy price of the stock. Doing the request in postman returns the desired information without any errors.

When I do this request in my local, I get the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=MSFT+GE&f=nab. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<title>Restangular</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mgonto/restangular/master/dist/restangular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="IndexCtrl" ng-cloak>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in people">{{person.Name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['restangular'])
        .config(function(RestangularProvider) {
            RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://finance.yahoo.com/d');
        });

    app.controller('IndexCtrl', function($scope, Restangular) {
        $scope.people = Restangular.all('quotes.csv?s=MSFT+GE&f=nab').getList();
    });
```

I'm confused by this error because since this is a public API and POSTMAN can access it, I'd assume that the header is already present in the API server. Why would I get this error when requesting from my local?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Posstman presumably adds the necessary Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.  You will have to do the same in your app otherwise the browser shuts you right down.  Enter the fascinating world of cors here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-cors-server-flowchart

Comment: That's wrong. The header is provided by the API, not be the person trying to request it. Postman doesn't have a problem because it does not comply with the cross origin policy for browsers, and lets you query whatever. Chrome doesn't let this person make the request because it does comply. Chrome is blocking the request. The correct solution is to use JSONP or CORS.

Comment: So I need to create a proxy server with CORS in order to make it work. I've had experience doing this once with PHP. Is there any other methods/examples where I can either just configure Apache to handle this or not use PHP?

Answer (score -1):

Here's me making a JSONP request which fails because it's trying to receive a CSV file. I don't think restangular knows how to read CSV files either which is what you are attempting. I think you need to do the same thing as you are now but using the YQL API instead because I don't think this is going to work.

Anyway here's the code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/GokYqzJ0dXw86C6AM2UP?p=preview

The request (which goes through but fails due to the file type):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $http.jsonp('http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv', {
    params: {
      callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
      s: 'MSFT GE',
      f: 'nab'
    }
  }).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
});
```